# Create user mapping without password how to configure authentication

Tags: postgresql, database-design, psql, postgresql-14, postgresql-fdw

I am trying to create a user mapping in PostgreSQL without a password, but I am encountering an error that says.

```
local_db=> select * from employee;
ERROR:  could not connect to server "testmachine02"
DETAIL:  connection to server at "192.168.56.10", port 5432 failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

Here is the command that I used to create the user mapping:

```
CREATE USER MAPPING for app_user SERVER testmachine02 OPTIONS (password_required 'false');
```

I also created a pgpass file under /root/.pgpass with the following entries:

```
localhost:5432:local_db:app_user:app_user123
192.168.56.10:5432:admin:admin:admin123
192.168.56.10:5432:remote_db:test:test123
```

Despite these steps, I am still unable to access the table without a password. How can I create a user mapping without a password and access the table?

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is that you created the password file in `root`'s home directory. It must be in the home directory of the user that owns the database server processes, probably `postgres`.

Make sure you set the ownership and permissions on the file as described by the documentation.

Comment: I gave the ownership to the user postgres already

Comment: But the location is wrong.

Comment: you mean it should be under /usr/pgsql-14/

Comment: Please perform a web search for "linux user home directory" or similar. I cannot divine what your bootstrap user is (probably `postgres`) nor what its home directory is (perhaps `/var/lib/pgsql`).

Comment: the user home directory is vagrant in my case

Comment: do you mean /var/lib/pgsql/14/data/ after running the command "ps auxw |  grep postgres | grep -- -D"

Comment: I created .pgpass file to test under /var/lib/pgsql/14/data/ /var/lib/pgsql/14/ and /var/lib/pgsql/ not bypassing the password

Comment: IAfter using 'su - postgres' to switch to the 'postgres' user, I created the '.pgpass' file in my home directory, which worked without issue. However, when attempting to read the information specified in the 'create user mapping for app_user server testmachine02' command, such as the 'test' user and 'test123' password, I encountered difficulties. What information should I include in the '.pgpass' file in order to retrieve the username and password?

Comment: You do no retrieve the username from the password file, only the password. Host, port, database and user in the password file must be just like in your foreign server and user mapping definition.